# Webdriver trying to click on button but receiving 'server did not provide a static trace'?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

Webdriver trying to click on button but receiving 'server did not provide a static trace'?

The button which I'm trying to click:

```
<div class="buynowbutton">
<input class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle buynow" aria-expanded="false" value="Buy Now" type="submit"/>
</div>
```

I have created the following method listed below, for example 96 builds would pass but then I would get 4 which would fail due to the indicated exception:

```
public void clickOnBuyNowButton() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement buyNowButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='Buy Now' and @value='Buy Now'])[2]"));
    boolean clicked = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while (!clicked && attempts < 5000) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buyNowButton)).isEnabled();
            actionMoveAndClick(buyNowButton);
            clicked = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable click on 'BuyNow' button | clickOnBuyNowButton()");
            Assert.fail("Method failed: waitAndClickElement");
        }
        attempts++;
    }
}
```

StackTrace

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//input[@value='Buy Now' and @value='Buy Now'])[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),
```

Comment: can't you just do `//input[@value='Buy Now']` ?

Comment: @Gbru I think you need to address a lot many issues here. 1. As tracelogs mentions `(//input[@value='Buy Now' and @value='Buy Now'])[2]` is not a valid xpath. 2. You need to limit the `wait` for `this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buyNowButton)).isEnabled();` 3. Consider showing us the `actionMoveAndClick(buyNowButton)` method. Thanks

Comment: @Shashwat this would locate many buttons with the same id?

Comment: @Dev i have screenshot which show the button is there :/ also action move and click seems to do the same thing :/

Comment: @Gbru then it doesn't matter. You are doing `@value='Buy Now'` twice, it doesn't change the scenario.

Comment: ok @Shashwat I will double check, but i think some special offers also use the same id / button for other products on the same page, thanks for your help

Comment: @Shashwat thanks changed to (//input[@value='Buy Now'])[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like timing issue, use the explicit wait to locate the button

```
WebElement buyNowButton = this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Buy Now'][position()=2]")));

boolean clicked = false;
int attempts = 0;
while (!clicked && attempts < 5000) {
    try {
        actionMoveAndClick(buyNowButton);
        clicked = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable click on 'BuyNow' button | clickOnBuyNowButton()");
        Assert.fail("Method failed: waitAndClickElement");
    }
    attempts++;
}
```

You also don't need the `Thread.sleep(2000);` and `isEnabled()`. If the button is clickable it is enabled, and you don't check the returned value anyway.

In addition, the `xpath` is not valid. If you want to select by index use `position()`.

Comment: why `@value='Buy Now'` twice in the Xpath ?

Comment: @Shashwat good question, didn't notice that. I just copied the OP `xpath`.

Comment: @Guy Its clear that the xpath is not a valid one. Though moving forward there will more issues as I mentioned in my previous comments. Thanks

Comment: @Guy thanks look like the combination of your code and changing the xpath seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

I remember an error like this in my code. Copying the xpath again helped me. I'm wondering a little about this xpath because the aspect Guy is saying and the simple quotes in the xpath. I only know double quotes in the xpath, which need to be escasped by backslashes.

If nothing works, you could use "findElement" by another identifier, for example "id" or "name".

Comment: thanks changed to the following: "(//input[@value=\"Buy Now\"])[2]"